# Regression for Analysing Fourier Transform of a Complex Function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, fourier-transform

Regression for Analysing Fourier Transform of a Complex Function

I need to analyse a linear system which is **y = FT{x}**,
where Input x and output y are both complex function (**A*exp(jθ)**).

If I **only have amplitude information of the input and output no phase information**, and I can collect the input and output data (only amplitude no phase) as many as I want.

My question is that can I get the **the phase information of the input and output** by using **linear regression**? Or is there any way to do that?